# Update an ImageView inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, caching, adapter

I'm stuck on this for hours,I'm trying to set an image for the first list item in my ListView but some ImageViews on the other list items are also changing.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ArrayList<ListItem> myItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    Player[] players;

    public MyAdapter() {
        DataBase banco = new DataBase(ScoreBoard.this);
        players = banco.consultaJogadores(); 
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; players[i] != null; i++) {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.caption = players[i].getName();
            myItems.add(listItem);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return myItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.topplayer, null);      
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topPlayerTextView);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topPlayerImageView);   
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }           
        holder.textView.setText(position + " " + players[position].getName() + " " + players[position].getScore());
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageview;
}

class ListItem {
    String caption;
}
```

I whant to change the image from the first player on the list.
Players at index 0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13 and 14 get updated, it does not follow a logical sequence.
And when I scroll, the images changes again.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recycling views, therefore when you don't want the listitems image to be set you have to explicitly de-set it:

```
if (position == 0) {
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
} else {
    holder.imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

(otherwise it will just remember the image that was set from the last time that that view ((i.e. convertView)) was used!

Comment: thanks. you cant set null to ImageResource, but I tried this: holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);

i will make something better late and i iwll remove image viw from ViewHolder.

so, thanks again, you saved me!

Comment: `setImageDrawable` , or yes use a transparent image resource

Comment: oh yeah, use a transparent image is better

but i will try to remove the ImageView

Comment: I cant check the answer as useful because I have less than 15 reputation score. but I will do that when i get more, thank you again and again :)

Comment: @Blundell : I spent several hours today on a similar issue and `holder.imageview.setImageDrawable(null);` works like a charm!!! Thanks!! Why stackoverflow only allows one single upvote?!